# How to allow toggling of Twitter Bootstrap modals within a PHP While loop

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop

The following shows my HTML & PHP for most of the tags on the page including the while loop. It loops out all the rows in a sql table, the user should be able to click on the image and it opens up a modal to be able to crop that image. This works perfectly fine in the first item on the page (first sql row), but for all subsequent sql rows the modal does not open after clicking. How can I correct this or troubleshoot it?

I'm using Twit BS 3.2.0

```
        <?php 
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once ('verify.php'); 
    ?>
    <head>
    <title>Edit Listings</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/crop-avatar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="head">
        <ul id="menu">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="area"></div>
      <div id="main_listings">
        <h1 align="left">Edit listings page</h1>
        <?php
    include ("../dbcon2.php");
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY date_added DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
        <?php while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                $id = $data['id'];
                $title = $data['title'];
                $listing_img = $data['listing_img'];
        ?>
        <div id="edit_listing">
          <div id="edit_left">
            <div class="container" id="crop-avatar">
              <div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar"> <img src="<?php echo $listing_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>"> </div>
              <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <form class="avatar-form" method="post" action="edit-avatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="avatar-modal-label">Listing Main Image</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="avatar-body">
                          <div class="avatar-upload">
                            <input class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src" type="hidden">
                            <input class="avatar-data" name="avatar_data" type="hidden">
                            <input name="avatar_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <label for="avatarInput">Local upload</label>
                            <input class="avatar-input" id="avatarInput" name="avatar_file" type="file">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                              <div class="avatar-wrapper"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="avatar-preview preview-lg"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary avatar-save" type="submit">Save</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="loading" tabindex="-1" role="img" aria-label="Loading"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="edit_right">
            <form name="edit_date" action="edit_list.php" method="post" id="edit_list_data">
              <input name="title" type="text" id="title" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" size="60" maxlength="57"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
              <input type="submit" formaction="edit_list.php" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;$conn->close();?>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/cropper.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/crop-avatar.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html><?php // Flush the buffered output.
        ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you setting $id = $data['id'] and then directly replacing the value with $data['title']?

Comment: @nullReference typo when I was minimizing my code for StackO. fixing, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have moved some things around and placed the bulk of the php before the initial html tag as well as placing the contents of the sql call into an array that is later used to build the images.

```
<?php 
include ("../dbcon2.php");

ob_start();
session_start();
require_once ('verify.php');

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY date_added DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$results = array();

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $results[] = array(
        'id'            =>  $data['id'];
        'title'         =>  $data['title'];
        'listing_img'   => $data['listing_img'];
    );

}

$conn->close();

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Listings</title>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/crop-avatar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="head">
    <ul id="menu">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="area"></div>
  <div id="main_listings">
    <h1 align="left">Edit listings page</h1>

    <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <div id="edit_listing">
      <div id="edit_left">
        <div class="container" id="crop-avatar">
          <div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar"><img src="<?php echo $row['listing_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"> </div>
          <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <form class="avatar-form" method="post" action="edit-avatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="avatar-modal-label">Listing Main Image</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="avatar-body">
                      <div class="avatar-upload">
                        <input class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src" type="hidden">
                        <input class="avatar-data" name="avatar_data" type="hidden">
                        <input name="avatar_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                        <label for="avatarInput">Local upload</label>
                        <input class="avatar-input" id="avatarInput" name="avatar_file" type="file">
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                          <div class="avatar-wrapper"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="avatar-preview preview-lg"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary avatar-save" type="submit">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="loading" tabindex="-1" role="img" aria-label="Loading"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="edit_right">
        <form name="edit_date" action="edit_list.php" method="post" id="edit_list_data">
          <input name="title" type="text" id="title" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" size="60" maxlength="57"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
          <input type="submit" formaction="edit_list.php" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>


    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/cropper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/crop-avatar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php // Flush the buffered output.
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```